# Find executing queries on Oracle 8

Tags: select, trace, oracle8i

I have a .NET application that uses parameterized queries to select data from an Oracle database. It seems that the parameters are not passed correctly or something, because I obtain different results in the application from those when executing the query directly on the database.

Therefore, I want to be able to see the select that is being executed on the server. How can I do that?

Comment: Yes, really! Why? I must say I'm fairly new to Oracle as I used to work with .net and his "rightful pair" SQLServer.

Comment: Oracle 8 has been de-supported for a very long time (I think at least 10 years or so). You should *really* upgrade to a version from this millenium (e.g. 11.2). It's like working with SQL Server 6.0